# Website Sitemap Drawing App or Tool

Tags: layout, web, sitemap, diagram, diagramming

Onetime I used 1 tool for to draw website sitemap, I forget the name of it and cant find it anymore. It is very easy to use and fast. I only have picture of 1 of mine drawings to show you to help me find out the name of it. I googled for a long time and nothing. It works you make a point and other point and type name of the 1st page and you continue to spread.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application is called Mindnode. You can get it here http://mindnode.com/.

Comment: wonderful, saved my day mate, splendid :P